# How to overwrite the add content page in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I need to change the default view of Add Content page in Drupal 7 so please any idea on how i can start is appreciated

Regards

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. Do you want to theme the page with a custom template or do you want to modify the initial add content form (add some fields, etc)?

Comment: thanks for replying, i need to modify the initial add content form to be like a table of all content type in my website and add two extra link near each content type for adding more content and for display the added ones already in website